# Regular expression for phone number: starts from + and all zeros not allowed

Tags: regex

Need a regular expression for phone number: starts from + and all zeros not allowed using JS. I tried the expression below but can't get the needed result.

```
phoneNumber.match(/^(\+)(\+0{24})[0-9\ \-\+]{6,25}$/)
```

Valid phone numbers:

- +49058737867800
- +31870900000789

Not valid numbers:

- +00000000000000000
- +49000000000000000
- 000000000000000000

Comment: Use: `/\+(?!0+$)[\d +-]{6,25}$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with a negative lookahead:

```
/^\+[1-9]{2}(?!0+$)[\d +-]{4,23}$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mDyC9K/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `\+`: Match `+`
- `[1-9]{2}`: Match digits `1-9` twice
- `(?!0+$)`: Negative lookahead to fail the match if we have only zeroes till end
- `[\d +-]{4,23}`: Match digit or space ot `+` or `-` between 4 to 23 times
- `$`: End